# Email connector with loopback 3

Tags: node.js, email, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I have a contact form and am using the PersistedModel for storing in the mysql table. Now i want to send the email with the values of the form. how to do this. I have tried using the loopback 3 Email connector but nothing is working i don't know how to do. Can anyone give me an example.

```
 <form class="form-area contact-form text-right" name="myForm" id="myForm"  novalidate >
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                           <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="text">
                           <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email address" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="email">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please Enter a Valid Email Id.</div>
                           <input name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Enter your subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your subject'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="text">
                           <div class="mt-20 alert-msg" style="text-align: left;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                           <textarea class="common-textarea form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Message'" required=""></textarea>
                           <button type="submit" class="primary-btn mt-20 text-white" style="float: right;">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </form>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
         $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
            var ins_date=new Date($.now()).toLocaleString();
         var parms = {
         name : $("#name").val(),
         email : $("#email").val(),
         subject : $("#subject").val(),
         message: $("#message").val(),
         inserted_date:ins_date
         };
         var url2="http://localhost:3000/api";
         $.ajax({
         method: 'POST',
         url: url2 + "/contacts",
         async: false,
         dataType : "json",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: JSON.stringify(parms),
         success: function(result){
         console.log('Submission was successful.');
         location.reload();
         console.log(data);
         }, error: function (data) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(data);
               },   
            })
      });
      </script>
```

datasource.json

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "mysql": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "url": "",
    "database": "mydb",
    "password": "pass",
    "name": "mysql",
    "user": "root",
    "connector": "mysql"
  },
 "email": {
    "name": "email",
    "connector": "mail",
    "transports": [
      {
        "type": "smtp",
        "host": "mail.company.com",
        "secure": true,
        "port": 465,
        "tls": {
          "rejectUnauthorized": false
        },
        "auth": {
          "user": "email@address.com",
          "pass": "password"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to send an email after saving in the table, fetch the id and send the values through email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add email datasource in loopback. Write send email function in `afterRemote` function.

Comment: I have added the email datasource in loopback . Do i need to create the seperate model for that

Comment: In datasource

`"mail": {
    "name": "mail",
    "connector": "mail",
    "transports": [
      {
        "type": "SMTP",
        "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
        "secure": true,
        "port": 465,
        "auth": {
          "user": "example@gmail.com",
          "pass": "1234567890"
        }
      }
    ]
  }`

and send email like this 

`User.app.models.Email.send({
              to: email,
              from: 'noreply@abc.com',
              subject: 'Password Reset Requested',
              text: 'Reset Password',
              html: html
            })`

Comment: can u tell me how to use remote method

Comment: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html . After writing one remote method , you can see it in Explorer

Comment: so i need to create a remote method after save for email email sending

Comment: No. If you want to send email you can use hooks

Comment: but after submitting the form i need to send email and it has to be stored in database also

Comment: Ex: If user created using User/post , then you can use `afterRemote`.There are `operation hook` and `remote hooks` present in loopback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190885/discussion-between-ashwanth-madhav-and-lakshmi-priya).

Comment: I need to send dynamic values in an email. For eg. once the contact form is submitted i need to fetch and send the same values in an email.